# Prevent MFC ActiveX control from using DLLs that are already loaded into the process

Tags: windows, dll, mfc, activex, manifest

**Short version**: How can an MFC ActiveX control loaded into a web page by Internet Explorer guarantee that its associated DLLs are loaded from its own directory, rather than picking up identically-named DLLs that might already be loaded into the process?

**Long version, with gory detail**: I have an application `myapp.exe` that uses a set of DLLs: `one.dll`, `two.dll` and `three.dll`.

The same DLLs are also used by an MFC ActiveX control that exposes some of the same functionality as `myapp.exe`, so there's a `mycontrol.ocx` that also links with those DLLs.  The ActiveX control is associated with the `application/myapp` MIME type, so that IE will use it to display documents created with `myapp.exe`.

It's possible to have both versions 1 and 2 of `myapp.exe` installed, but only the most recent version of `mycontrol.ocx` (version 2) is associated with the `application/myapp` MIME type:

```
c:\Program Files\MyApp\Version 1\
                                 myapp.exe
                                 mycontrol.ocx
                                 one.dll
                                 two.dll
                                 three.dll
c:\Program Files\MyApp\Version 2\
                                 myapp.exe
                                 mycontrol.ocx  <-- registered with the MIME type
                                 one.dll
                                 two.dll
                                 three.dll
```

Here's where it it gets difficult: `myapp.exe` has an embedded Internet Explorer control for displaying web content.  You can run version 1 of `myapp.exe`, point that embedded Internet Explorer at an `application/myapp` document, and IE will load up version 2 of `mycontrol.ocx` to view it.  This ought to be fine, but it's not:

What happens is that Windows loads `mycontrol.ocx`, sees that it has a dependency on `one.dll` and that there's already a `one.dll` in the process, and points the import table of `mycontrol.ocx` with the already-loaded (version 1) `one.dll`, rather than loading version 2 of `one.dll`.  This fails because version 2 of `mycontrol.ocx` uses new APIs in version 2 of `one.dll` that weren't there in version 1.

**How do I stop it doing that?**  If `one.dll` weren't already loaded, Windows would look in `c:\Program Files\MyApp\Version 2` for it, and all would be well.  (And I can't rename all my modules for every version of the software!)

**Failed solution #1**: I gave `mycontrol.ocx` a manifest that specifies `<file ...>` elements for all the DLLs, but that doesn't work.  `one.dll` gets loaded from the `Version 2` directory, but `two.dll` doesn't.  I assume this is because `two.dll` is being loaded as a result of `one.dll` referencing it, and `one.dll` doesn't have such a manifest.

**Failed solution #2**: So I added a manifest to **all** the DLLs, each listing its dependncies in `<file ...>` elements.  But that broke `myapp.exe` completely, because MFC now treats each DLL as having its own activation context and that's not right - there should be one MFC context for the whole process (in the case of `myapp.exe`) or the whole instance of the control (in the case of `mycontrol.exe`).  I can't have a new activation context for each module; I need one for the whole of `mycontrol.ocx` and its attendant DLLs.

I changed all the manifests to use the same `name=` attribute, in the hope that that would put them all into the same context, but that had no effect.

**Failed solution #3**: I gave `myapp.exe` a manifest that said `<file name="mycontrol.ocx"/>` in the hope of forcing version 1 of the app to use version 1 of the control, which would be fine.  But that fails because when Internet Explorer loads `mycontrol.ocx` it calls `LoadLibrary` with the full path to version 2 of `mycontrol.ocx`, and manifest redirection doesn't work when modules are loaded using a full path.

**Something I can't do**: I can't change the code that loads the control, because it's Internet Explorer doing that (via the MIME type).

Any solutions, suggestions or simple messages of sympathy will be gratefully received.

Comment: #2 above makes the most sense, but I don't know what you mean by "MFC now treats each DLL as it's own activation context and that's not right".  What is an Activation Context?  Why does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how I solved this in the end:**

I split `mycontrol.ocx` into two pieces, `mycontrol.dll` that implements the functionality, and a minimal `mycontrol.ocx` that implements the registration logic and acts as a shim to the real module.  The shim `mycontrol.ocx` has no DLL dependencies.  Here's what it does:

- If there's a `mycontrol.dll` next to the executable that started the process, this must be a new-version `myapp.exe` and the shim loads that `mycontrol.dll` and reflects `DllGetClassObject` and `DllCanUnloadNow` calls to it.
- If there's a `mycontrol.ocx` but no `mycontrol.dll` next to the executable, this must be an old-version `myapp.exe`, so the shim loads up that `mycontrol.ocx` and redirects to that.
- If neither module exists, this must be a web browser or some other ActiveX host, so the shim loads up the `mycontrol.dll` that's in the same directory as itself, and redirects to that.

It's a bit more complex than that in real life, but the result is that everybody loads the code they were expecting to load, and it all works.

Answer (score 1):

One option to try might be to specify the OCX's DLL dependencies as delay loaded, and then write your own delay-load helper function that used LoadLibraryEx() to be certain of loading the DLLs from the path you want to use. I have experimented with this in the past and got it to work with an executable, but I don't see why it wouldn't work with an OCX.

MSDN has decent documentation on [using the delay loading helper function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09t6x5ds.aspx). In the delay load helper function you want to concentrate on the "dliNotePreLoadLibrary" case, and return the HMODULE of the right DLL that you've got with LoadLibraryEx().

By the way, in the end I didn't use this approach: I just made sure all the DLLs have the version number in them. In the end, it's the easiest way ...

Comment: +1 for a very good idea, but sadly I can't use it.  My code makes extensive use of exported C++ classes, whereby `one.dll` uses `TwoClass` that's exported from `two.dll`.  That makes `one.dll` import the data symbol `TwoClass::vftable` from `two.dll`, and hence the link fails when you specify `/delayload:two.dll`, because importing a data symbol precludes delayload.  (Interestingly, it works in a Debug build - vtables must be different there.  If I could find a way to make Release builds treat vtables the same as Debug builds, I might be OK, but I can't.)

Comment: Ouch, that's nasty. Shame MS haven't come up with a sensible way to delay load with C++ classes. The only remaining thing I can suggest would be to break up the OCX logic so that as much as possible is in a third DLL that can be LoadLibraryEx()d into the process :-(

Comment: See my answer for how I eventually solved this, which did involve "breaking up the OCX logic so that as much as possible is in a third DLL" - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Knowing a bit about DLL hell, I don't know anything about "MFC Activation Context".  That's why your #2 idea above seems solid.

But if that doesn't work you, three possible solutions I would try and investigate:

1. Crazy idea.  When you register "mycontrol.ocx" in the registry as being associated with application/myapp, you currently have it registered by it's FULL path (c:\program files\app\version2\mycontrol.ocx").  Just register it as "mycontrol.ocx" with no directory specified.  If you're lucky, IE control will "LoadLibrary("mycontrol.ocx") and find it from the same directory as your EXE.  This of course breaks if you actually need mycontrol.ocx to load within a standalone instance of IE. But perhaps you could have an alternate MIME type (or com guid) for external pages to load the control directly.
2. In your application's installation, put the EXE in a different directory than the DLLs.  Then use [the "AppPath" registry key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872121%28VS.85%29.aspx) to virtually add the specific DLL directory to the path of the app.  The only problem is that I don't think you can set an AppPath key name with a fully qualified path.  But I do know you can have an EXE name with a fully qualified path to a differently named EXE.  So we can "virtually rename" the second instance of "myapp.exe" as "myapp2.exe".  In your desktop shortcuts and start menu entry points, they all launch "myapp2.exe", but that gets redirected to "version2\app\myapp.exe"

   ```
   c:\Program Files\MyApp\Version 1\app\
                                         myapp.exe
   c:\program files\MyApp\Version 1\dll\
                                         mycontrol.ocx
                                         one.dll
                                         two.dll
                                         three.dll

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\myapp.exe
         (default)=c:\program files\MyApp\Version1\app\myapp.exe (type == REG_EXPAND_SZ)
         Path=c:\program files\MyApp\Version1\dll;c:\program files\MyApp\Version1\app;



   c:\program files\MyApp\Version 2\app\
                                        myapp.exe
   c:\program files\MyApp\Version 2\dll\
                                         mycontrol.ocx
                                         one.dll
                                         two.dll
                                         three.dll


   // NOTICE THE VIRTUAL RENAME TO MYAPP2 in the line below
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\myapp2.exe 
         (default)=c:\program files\MyApp\Version 2\app\myapp.exe (type == REG_EXPAND_SZ)
         Path=c:\program files\MyApp\Version 2\dll;c:\program files\MyApp\Version 2\app;
   ```
3. Use [Windows Side by Side installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369532%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and appropriate manifests in your EXEs and DLLS.

Comment: About MFC: MFC keeps a bunch of global state, and that state needs to be shared between the EXE and the DLLs that make up a process.  Adding manifests to the DLLs seems to make MFC treat them as separate, maintaining separate "global" state for each of them, and hence breaking any code that relies on the state being shared.

Comment: #1: Sadly I do need the control to work in standalone IE, and there's no difference between "external pages" and the pages being loaded by the app. #2: Sadly again, prior to Windows 7 App Paths requires Admin privileges to modify, and the app needs to be installable by non-admin users. #3: Well yes, that's what I'm trying to do. :-)

Comment: What if you did this.  Implement #1 above, but don't do it during setup or in HKLM.  When the app starts up, have it set the COM registration GUID for mycontrol.ocx to point to "mycontrol.ocx" without a specific path - using HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Classes\CLSID.  This will override the global registration.  When the app exits, it restores the registry.